# Windows Update Troubleshooter - Errors reappear after fixing

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I'm using Windows 8.1 64bit.

I had an issue with the Windows Modules Installer Worker using a high percentage of CPU when no updates were available. I ran the Windows Update troubleshooter and it seems that problems were found and fixed:

**Potential Windows Update Database error detected 0x80070490**

Possible issues may prevent Windows Update from keeping your system up to date.

**Windows Update components must be repaired**

One or more Windows Update components are configured incorrectly.

The issues with Windows Modules Installer Worker's high CPU usage stopped. However, a few hours later it started again. Sure enough, when I ran the troubleshooter again it showed the same errors had been found and fixed. I re-ran the troubleshooter straight after "fixing" and it's claiming the same errors are present and have been fixed.

Any suggestions??

Comment: capture a xperf trace when you see the high CPU usage again: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Answer (score 1):

After the same issue on Windows 8.1 update, I followed the instructions at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958044, specifically using SFC and DISM, which backed out some of the updates that had been partially installed. It then required going through the normal Windows Update process multiple times but resolved the issue. There's more from MS at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_update/how-do-i-fix-error-code-0x80070490windows-update/38fa3ffc-6361-4c14-83d3-13bc5c3a9047.

Please let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I'd just like to say that there are circumstances, undefined of course, when none of all the solutions one can find on the Web work. In my case (Windows 8.1), sfc and DSIM found no errors. The troubleshooter keeps finding the same 0x80070490 error again and again over a dozen consecutive runs, which all lead to a 100% occupation on a core. I'm lucky enough to have a CloneZilla image that I can restore onto the SSD; I hope the problem wasn't already there.